# using controller variable in javascript in phoenix

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to use a variable which is passed from controller to view in render parameters to be used in javascript and how to do it?

Comment: you need to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable passed from controllers can be used in javascript as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("<%= @var %>")
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use [PhoenixGon](https://github.com/khusnetdinov/phoenix_gon) it generates script tag with variables and additional methods for simplicity. It generate all stuff for you. You only need to use it from `window.Gon` or `wundow.YouApplicationNamespace`. And you don't need other rendering and data attributing in html.

In controller:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  conn = put_gon(conn, :variable, :value)
  render conn, "index.html"
end
```

In js module or browser console:

```
window.Gon.getAsset('variable')
# => 'value'
```

It also keeps Mix.env for using in js.